# Python Struct Pack Rounding

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to convert float to hex data with struct.pack with below functions

```
print(CurrentLimit)
print(type(CurrentLimit))
hexListValue = hexListValue + list(struct.pack('<f', float(CurrentLimit)))
print(self.hexToFloat(hexListValue))
```

this is convert function:

```
def hexToFloat(self,hexArray = []):
    ba = bytes(hexArray)
    return (struct.unpack('<f', ba)[0])
```

But it's give me below lines:

```
200.7
<class 'str'>
200.6999969482422
```

CurrentLimit is 200.7 but if I convert hex to float again I get    `200.6999969482422` vaue why I didnt get `200.7`

I need to pack correctly because when I pack the this float number I get 4 byte hex, and I send these data to other device. Other device convert this data to 200.6999969482422. So I need to pack this data as a 200.7

When I send the hexArray to stm32 device:

```
float HexToFloatConverter(uint8_t *hexArray)
{
 float convertedValue = 0.0;
 memcpy(&convertedValue,hexArray, sizeof(convertedValue)); 
 return convertedValue;
}
```

above function converts to hexarray to float. Is this possible to convert correct number ?

Comment: `f` is a *single* precision float. Python's `float` is *double* precision. You need the `d` format.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to have a [MRE] and meaningful title? The current state does not seem suitable for people with the same problem to realize that.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi unfortunately what he is asking for is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with float's resolution.

Please use a double like so:

```
>>> struct.unpack("<d", struct.pack("<d", float("200.7")))[0]
200.7
```

For more info, see the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) module's documentation.

---

As requested in the comment section, keep in mind that **it's impossible** for another device out of your control to get a 4-byte single precision float representing the number `200.7`. The float specification does not support it.

Comment: But unpack not solution for me because when I pack to data convert 4 byte hex value, I send this data with serial line so other device convert this data also 200.6999969482422. How to pack this 200.7 number correctl y?

Comment: @gogogo It's impossible for another device out of your control to get a single precision float representing the number 200.7.

Comment: I added my HexToFloatConverter function from the other side. I send hex array from the python than I obtain the float number in stm32 . If it is imposible from the ST side, okey than