# How to convert float to 4 byte hex value without pack in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I give a number in lineEdit text area. This lineEdit gets float numbers form the users.
userValue gives me this float number.

`print(type(userValue))` gives me "`str`" type.

If the users enter the number like a `0.9` , I need to convert this float number to 4 byte, I did this converting with this line : `list(struct.pack('<f', float(userValue)))`
But this value return double precision value. When I return the data from the hexToFloat or another device code HexToFloatConverter I get as a 0.8999999999212 number. How can I convert float to hex whit correct 4 bytes without struct.pack using ?

What is the another method return 0.9 number to 4 byte hex value correctly ?

```
def hexToFloat(self,hexArray = []):
    ba = bytes(hexArray)
    return (struct.unpack('<f', ba)[0])
```

This is another device code :

```
float HexToFloatConverter(uint8_t *hexArray)
{
 float convertedValue = 0.0;
 memcpy(&convertedValue,hexArray, sizeof(convertedValue)); 
 return convertedValue;
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's returning a double precision value? `0.899999...` looks fairly believable as a 32bit floating point value for 0.9. You're never going to be able to guarantee exact values as some values aren't representable in a 32bit float.

Comment: The ``f`` format marks a single precision float. If you think it does not, please provide a [mre]. If you do not want to use ``struct.pack``, please clarify what your requirements for a replacement are.

Comment: I added an approximate function in my topic

Comment: The code looks identical to [your recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70345165/python-struct-pack-rounding). What's the difference? Neither of the two new code snippets uses ``struct.pack`` as the previous part of the question does, how do they relate?

Comment: I dont want to use STRUCT PACK for the float to hex convert. I am looking for ANOTHER method. In my last topic, if I use the struct pack they say it is impossible.

Comment: Is your issue with ``struct.pack`` in specific (if so, which?) or with 0.9 not being represented accurately on a single precision float? What would another method need to return for it to "return 0.9 number to 4 byte hex value correctly" – what is the expected output?

Comment: In the other question, you were informed that single precision float is not suitable to represent your number as desired. Whether one uses ``struct.pack`` or not does not change what the format can express.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point math is hard. `0.89999...` is a valid representation for 0.9 in floating point math. The problem is with floats rather than with `struct.pack`.

You would need to clean up the number yourself:

```py
import struct
def pack_float(my_float: float) -> bytes:
    return struct.pack('<f', my_float)

def unpack_float(my_bytes: bytes) -> float:
    unpacked_float = struct.unpack_from('<f', my_bytes)[0]
    rounded = round(unpacked_float, ndigits=2)
    return rounded

packed = pack_float(0.9)
unpacked = unpack_float(packed)
print(unpacked)

# Outputs 0.9
```

This will be fine for numbers with a 'few' significant digits (I think 5 significant figures or 2 decimal places is *mostly* accurate).

If you need more accuracy/precision, you'll need to adjust one of your requirements.
As an example, using the 8 byte <s>`decimal`</s> `d` double format, its *mostly* accurate at 14 significant figures or 6 decimal places:

```py
import struct
def pack_float(my_float: float) -> bytes:
    return struct.pack('d', my_float)

def unpack_float(my_bytes: bytes) -> float:
    unpacked_float = struct.unpack_from('<f', my_bytes)[0]
    rounded = round(unpacked_float, ndigits=6)
    return rounded

packed = pack_float(0.9)
unpacked = unpack_float(packed)
print(unpacked)

# Outputs 0.9
```

Comment: ``d`` is not "decimal format", it's "*d*ouble precision format" – as opposed to ``f``'s "single precision format".

Comment: wow you're right, if I cast the unpacked value to `decimal.Decimal()` you can see the float artifacts after around 15 decimal places. Will tweak the answer, thanks